# mysql automatically sets UNHEX for LONGBLOB in database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, blob

Hi I am storing some images in MySQL DB in a LONGBLOB field. Whenever this image is stored MySQL sets the function for this column to UNHEX. I dont want this to be automatically set to that. My BLOBs used to work fine when this was not set. How do I remove this UNHEX being set by default.

I am using phpmyadmin, MySQL, InnoDB and PHP to retrieve those images. I used to get back the images perfectly fine before we migrated to a new version of phpmyadmin.

Please help.

Comment: What version of phpmyadmin did you use before, and what version do you use now?

Comment: @William 3.2 before and 3.3 now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the phpmyadmin changelog (http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/changelog.php), it does appear there are a few issues noted regarding this problem with earlier versions of PMA (see the note under 3.4.0.0 about defaulting to UNHEX). You might want to upgrade to the latest version and see if these problems still exist.